# How to find nullclines

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently working on the following question, which I'm stuck at:

> Given the following system of differential equations, which is 
>   $$\frac{dR}{dt} = 2R - 4RF$$
>   $$\frac{dF}{dt} = RF-F$$

To find the R-nullcline, we set $\frac{dR}{dt} = 0$ and we get $$2R(1-2F) = 0$$

So $R = 0$ or $1-2F = 0$

To find the F-nullcline, we set $\frac{dF}{dt} = 0$ and we yield

$$F(R-1) = 0$$

So $F = 0$ or $R-1 = 0$.

Assuming that I did everything correct up to this point, what are my nullclines that I need to graph? I would like to learn how to graph this system by hand, but using Mathematica to generate a plot works too (labeling the axes would help too).

**P.S.** Somewhat of a side question, but are these my steady-state solutions too?

Comment: [Here's a quick guide to nullclines](https://mcb.berkeley.edu/courses/mcb137/exercises/Nullclines.pdf)

Comment: Funny thing is that I ran into that same link just before logging back in. This should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $R=0$ represents a straight line – just draw it! And $2F-1=0$ is another straight line – draw that one too! The union of those two lines is your $R$-nullcline.

The $F$-nullcline: similarly.

Steady states = points of intersections between the $R$-nullcline and the $F$-nullcline.

Comment: Slight typo on my part Hans. It should be $1-2F = 0$. I just edited my OP.